# user type, parent, send all in form is better?

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my Form, I think put parent, user_type, send email all in form's save is good choice, do you have more better solution? tell me the reasons.

```
class UserType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=settings.USER_TYPES, unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_type(cls, user_type):
        # avoided fat finger, right? predefine the user type
        return UserType.objects.get_or_create(name=user_type)[0]


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = UserManager()
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(u"UUID", default=uuid.uuid1, unique=True, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(u'Email', max_length=30, unique=True, null=True,
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', u'email format error')
        ])
    perms = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=settings.PERMS), blank=True)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.UserType',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='users',
    )


class StaffUser(User):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='staff_childs',
    )


class StaffForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = StaffUser
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'perms']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ## if you use CreateView, you can use get_form_kwargs pass extra paramter
    self.parent = kwargs.pop('parent')
    return super(StaffForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def save(self):
    self.instance.parent = self.parent
    self.instance.user_type = UserType.get_type(settings.STAFF)
    user = super(StaffForm, self).save()
    # send email
    return user
```

## update

```
class StaffCreateView(CreateView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(StaffCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'parent': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

And there is another question, should I just let the parent field put into the user who need parent, not like this: parent = User(null=True). Because not every user need to parent. If you register yourself in register page, you need not parent field, and your model NormalUser(User) need not parent field too. I just mean parent is only belong to who needs it ,so I should put it in the User model, right ?

Comment: Looks like a good solution to me.

Comment: Thanks, I send email after all save success, because if any error occur, I can scroll back the database.

Comment: Yeah that seems perfectly normal using django transactions

Comment: I update it ,because I test not passed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your staffuser model

```
class StaffUser(User):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='staff_childs',
        null=True
    )
```

Then you just don't set it in the save method.

```
def save(self, parent):
    if parent:
        self.instance.parent = parent
```

Comment: sorry, every StaffUser need to parent, I mean other type user may be not need to parent, for example you register yourself in register page. now you are another user mode like NormalUser(User), I mean don't put parent in the User model.

Comment: You don't have a parent field on your user model so you can't set it on that

Comment: Yeah, I think so, but some people tell me: if the StaffUser don't have too much extra information, put all of them to User, but I think it's not right, do you ?

Comment: Yeah just use the user model it already has is_staff field then you can just check against that field

Comment: is_staff, I already remove it( let it here, not use, because I have user type table, and I have 5+ user types)

Comment: and there may be a problem: if you use CreateView, how to call save like this: save(parent=request.user)

Comment: You can remove the type model and just use a choicefield and you will need to override the method on the createview

Comment: no, I think use UserType is good choice, and I the form question, I use one way to fixed it, I will update it quickly.

Comment: ok, and I update my code, and I think it's good now, may be I can anwser myself : )

Comment: You've overridden the view like I said ;)